# Recorded Animation appearing as Recorded, but not moving when animating?

Tags: animation

Today, I recorded animation and it is showing up in the bottom bar but when I animate it two of the shapes I animated aren't even appearing b/c the animation ends with them off screen. But it starts with them on, so I don't know... Also the shapes that are there on camera won't move... Please Help

Here is the screen when editing
[image]

Here is the screen when animating
[image]

Comment: Is this the same animation i helped you with before? To render it you need to press the Animate button in the Render tab, not F12.

Comment: A different animation same shapes, and I have been pressing animate

Comment: Oh, and also, the internal blender viewer to my understanding, does not play vidoes, and thus you must go to where you saved it and play it from there using whatever software you have for playing videos.

Comment: I tried that even the video that it exported doesn't show the movement

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1229" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1229/)

Comment: Here is the .blend on blend exchange

Comment: Your starting point for the animation is around 60, nothing happens from 60 to the end, when i set it to 0 i see the objects fall, i am now rendering this, and so far it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

At the near bottom of your screen set the beginning keyframe to 0. Play the animation and then set it back to 63.

Another way is just set the current keyframe to 0 and hold down right arrow until it's at the keyframe you want it to stop the animation at. This is because of the way rigidbody animations work, it has to play at least once to record the motion it will take, you could say.

Answer (score 0):

In shading view, in the upper right there are three circle tabs: camera, hand and magnify. Click the camera. I had the same issue and that worked for me.